# How to download nested json data, convert to excel format in angular 10?

Tags: angular, angular10

```json
employees = [
  {
    SNO : 1,
    name : "HARIPRASATH",
    SALARY : [
      {
        SNO: 1,
        MONTH : 'APRIL',
        DATE : '01-04-2022',
        TIME : '10.AM',
        AMOUNT : 15000
      },
      {
        SNO: 2,
        MONTH : 'MAY',
        DATE : '01-05-2022',
        TIME : '10.AM',
        AMOUNT : 15000
      },
      {
        SNO: 3,
        MONTH : 'JUNE',
        DATE : '01-06-2022',
        TIME : '10.AM',
        AMOUNT : 15000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    SNO : 2,
    name : "SINDHUJA",
    SALARY : [
      {
        SNO: 1,
        MONTH : 'APRIL',
        DATE : '01-04-2022',
        TIME : '10.AM',
        AMOUNT : 18000
      },
      {
        SNO: 2,
        MONTH : 'MAY',
        DATE : '01-05-2022',
        TIME : '10.AM',
        AMOUNT : 18000
      },
      {
        SNO: 3,
        MONTH : 'JUNE',
        DATE : '01-06-2022',
        TIME : '10.AM',
        AMOUNT : 18000
      }
    ]
  }
```

I need to convert this table type to excel format like this:
[image: I NEED THIS TABLE TYPE EXCEL FORMAT]

Comment: please ask question along with code so that people can understand what you're trying to do

Comment: u can use dev extreme package that need json and display table and if u need u can dawnload data as excel file